# Why were Edward, Henry and Toby dropped from the steam team?

Tags: character, thomas-and-friends

In the later series of *Thomas and Friends* why were Edward, Henry and Toby dropped from the steam team and what happened to them?

Answer (score 1):

To make space for diversity, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_%26_Friends_(series_22)#:%7E:text=Among%20many%20other%20changes%2C%20Edward,still%20works%20on%20the%20series):

> Among many other changes, Edward, Henry and Toby have been removed from the Steam Team to make room for Nia and Rebecca

From [The Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/4688268/thomas-the-tank-engine-revamp-female-foreign-characters-un-diversity/)

> Henry and Edward will get the boot from Tidmouth Sheds to make room
> for Nia and Rebecca – who will come from the Mainland near Thomas'
> fictional island of Sodor.
>
> Producers want the two new female characters to have starring roles
> when they join Emily, who has been the only girl engine among the main
> characters for around 13 years.
>
> Ian McCue, one of the producers, said: "We have added new female
> characters before, but I think, with a show like Thomas, they tend to
> fall into the background after initial introduction.
>
> **"What we wanted to do here was really bring these two female
> characters to the forefront."**